# Flutter FirebaseAuth: SignInWithEmailAndPassword unable to handle error when the email address is badly formatted

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, firebase-authentication

Here is my email sign in method in my FirebaseAuthService class:

```
  @override
  Future<UserCustom> signInWithEmail(
      String emailAddress, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential _signInWithEmailAndPasswordGoogle = await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailAddress, password: password);
      if (_signInWithEmailAndPasswordGoogle.user != null) {
        return _userToUserModel(_signInWithEmailAndPasswordGoogle.user);
      } else {
        throw PlatformException(
            code: 'SIGN_IN_INTERRUPTED', message: 'Sin in interrupted');
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      print('Happened');
      rethrow;
    } 
  }
```

And here is where the exception should be handled:

```
  // creating the submit function
  Future<void> _submit(EmailSignInModelProviderPattern model) async {
    // if it is on sign in use sign in function ELSE use register function
    try {
      await model.submit();
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      CustomErrorPlatformException(
        title: 'Sign in failed',
        exception: e,
      ).show(context);
    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

And yet when I enter a badly formatted address the process is interrupted at `message_codecs.dart` file at the method `dynamic decodeEnvelope(ByteData envelope){...` line 572 with error message: [image: See screenshot]

> Exception has occurred. PlatformException
> (PlatformException(firebase_auth,
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The
> email address is badly formatted., {code: invalid-email,
> additionalData: {}, message: The email address is badly formatted.}))

I couldn't figure out how to handle this exception, knowing that it never happened to me before upgrading to firebase_auth: `^0.18.0+1`.

Answer (score 2):

check this issues where it explains why is happens
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1760

.
If you use an Emulator and change textfield with tab button then there's an extra space left behind on that email field ->*myemail@gmail.com *

to avoid this extra space you have to use `.trim()` method.

in your case

```
UserCredential _signInWithEmailAndPasswordGoogle = await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailAddress.trim(), password: password);
```

I guess this solves your problem.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem at hand, the problem is that invalid input is not handled inside the Firebase Service class nor in the Firebase Auth library anymore, the error is thrown from the `message_codecs.dart` file which is part of the flutter SDK.
Doesn't matter if the input is trimmed, the error should be handled inside the `Future<void> _submit(EmailSignInModelProviderPattern model) async {...` method. But it doesn't anymore since the last upgrade of the FlutterFire package.

Comment: This helped me. As there was email autofill on the keyboard there was an extra space being added, so there was a problem signing in. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, your code looks fine. Try disabling **Uncaught Expectations** in the Debugging panel for VScode solved the issue for me.
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3303#issuecomment-687560133