# The email address is badly formatted, [firebase_auth/invalid-email]

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication

This is my code ..
And this is running successfully there are no errors but once i clicked on Sign-up button its throws the error.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Homepage(),
    routes: {
      '/home': (context) {
        return Homepage();
      },
      '/first': (context) {
        return First_Page();
      },
    },
  ));
}

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _user = TextEditingController();
  final _pass = TextEditingController();
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text(
          'Sign-Up',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 250),
            ),
            Container(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _user,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Email-id",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _pass,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Password",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('Sign-up'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await Firebase.initializeApp();
                email = _user.toString();
                password = _pass.toString();
                final newuser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email.trim(),
                  password: password.trim(),
                );
                if (newuser != null) {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/First_Page');
                } else
                  print('Error');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

These are the all errors that i am getting

```
  E/flutter (10268): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 
  [firebase_auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted.
  E/flutter (10268): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword 
  (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel
  /method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:272:7)
  E/flutter (10268): <asynchronous suspension>
  E/flutter (10268): #1      FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword 
  (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:238:7)
  E/flutter (10268): <asynchronous suspension>
  E/flutter (10268): #2      _HomepageState.build.<anonymous closure> 
  (package:firebase/main.dart:79:31)
   E/flutter (10268): <asynchronous suspension>
   E/flutter (10268):
```

And in firebase authentication I already enabled the email sign in method, now i am not getting where i mistaken.
plz tell me .Thanks in advance..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559653/flutter-firebaseauth-signinwithemailandpassword-unable-to-handle-error-when-the?

Comment: I already checked this and applied all the methods that are mentioned there but still not working @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `email` address you're using:

```
email=_user.toString();
```

With `_user` being:

```
final _user=TextEditingController()
```

So you're calling `toString` on a `TextEditingController`, which gives you a debug representation of that controller. If you want the value from that controller, you'll want to use:

```
email=_user.value;
```

---

To spot this type of problem yourself, I recommend learning to set breakpoints and use a debugger. If you set a breakpoint on the `_auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` (which is where the exception comes from) and run in the debugger, you can easily see that `email` does not have the value you expect. From there it should be a matter of tracing backwards to where the value comes from, and looking at the [documentation for `TextEditingController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) to see the correct call.